# Finding 3 equal consecutive numbers in two different Arrays. Java

Tags: java

I am writing a program that reads a CSV file and stores each column into a separate array. later I want to search arrays A and B and make for 3 consecutive 0s and then 2 ones following them. An example of the console after I run the program is;

```
                                            A   B
Line # 1    1.3167  1.3164  1.318   1.3174  0   0
Line # 2    1.3167  1.3164  1.318   1.3174  0   0
Line # 3    1.3175  1.3164  1.3182  1.3169  0   0
Line # 4    1.3168  1.3167  1.3225  1.3212  1   1
Line # 5    1.3213  1.3206  1.3221  1.321   1   0
Line # 6    1.3211  1.3208  1.3241  1.3239  1   1
Line # 7    1.324   1.3237  1.3262  1.3242  1   1
Line # 8    1.3243  1.3234  1.3271  1.3245  0   1
Line # 9    1.3244  1.3223  1.3251  1.324   0   0
Line # 10   1.3241  1.3226  1.3269  1.3269  1   1
```

There are many more lines, however I want the program to find and a message to me every time the pattern from line 1-4 occur.

My code is

```
package pacakge;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class read {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException  {
    int size=0;
    double[] open = new double[1000000];
    double[] low = new double[1000000];
    double[] high = new double[1000000];
    double[] close = new double[1000000];
    int[] A = new int[1000000];
    int[] B = new int[1000000];

    int zeroCount = 0;

    Scanner read = new Scanner(new File("C:/Users/Eric/Documents/Data Structures/EURUSD.csv"));
    read.nextLine();
    while(read.hasNextLine()) {
      String[] n= read.nextLine().split(",");
      open[size]=Double.parseDouble(n[0]);
      low[size]=Double.parseDouble(n[1]);
      high[size]=Double.parseDouble(n[2]);
      close[size]=Double.parseDouble(n[3]);
      A[size]=Integer.parseInt(n[4]);
      B[size]=Integer.parseInt(n[5]);
      size++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
      System.out.println(open[i] + "\t" + low[i] + "\t" + high[i] + "\t" + close[i] + "\t" + A[i] + "\t" + B[i]);
      System.out.println("Line" + i);
      System.out.println(open[68722]);

      if(A[i]==0 && A[i+1] == 0 && A[i+2] == 0 && B[i]==0 && B[i+1] == 0 && B[i+2] == 0) {
        zeroCount++;
        System.out.println("Found Pattern !!!" + zeroCount);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After I run it runs fine, but it finds three 0s however, the order isn't consecutive. I'm not sure why this is not working. Thank you.

Comment: If this were my code, I'd sprinkle it with println statements to try to isolate the error. I'd also try to avoid creating parallel arrays and instead hold each row of data in a single object of a custom class.

Comment: I need the CSV to be manipulable, I wasn't able to think of a way I can separate the values to compare them to each other. Is there a better way you could show me?

Comment: I foresee a problem in your second loop. You loop until i = size -1 and then try and look at A[i+1] and A[i+2], as well as B[i+1] and B[i+2], all of which will result in an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. The reason you haven't seen this yet is because of short circuit evaluation and the fact that you haven't ran the program with A[size-1] = 0 yet.

Comment: I think what @HovercraftFullOfEels is saying is that you could create a Class that has fields for `open, low, high, close, A, and B` and then create 1 array of that Class rather than creating 6 arrays that hold the primitives. Then you could create a constructor that takes in the String array created by the `split` function and builds the Class instance.

Comment: @Eric: Sure, create your objects, and compare A column by calling getA() from the two objects you'd like to compare. Same for getB(). Or, you could give your class a method to compare both A and B columns at the same time, a compareAandB(...).

Answer (score 0):

A simpler and perhaps more efficient solution to your problem is to convert these arrays A and B you have into String Astring and Bstring where each character in the string is an element in your array: i.e. if

```
A={0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,...};
```

Then Astring is:

```
Astring="00011110...";
```

Once you have this, finding what you are looking for is achieved in one line:

```
int index = Astring.indexOf("00011");
```

if index=-1, you do not have the sequence 0,0,0,1,1 you were looking for.  Otherwise, A(index) will be the first element in the pattern you were looking for (i.e. A(index)=0, A(index+1)=0, ..., A(index+4)=1).